# SQL column value changing

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I have a table which has a column `result` with values `passed, failed, pending` etc.. if my result value is passed i have to change result = passed to result = corrected How can I do this within a where clause. That is if result is passed i want to change passed to corrected. I tried the following

```
select result as status, address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip as occupancy, name 
from Occupancies OCC 
where (address like '%rd' or address is not null ) and
        case when result = 'Passed' then ' corrected';
```

I am already using some conditions in where clause. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the expected output? What SQL are you using - oracle, mysql, mssql..?

Comment: The like is never evaluated, since not null covers the like part rows as well. You probably want `(address like '%rd' or address is null )`.

Comment: I am using sql server. The desired output is wherever my value is passed instead of displaying as passed it should display as corrected

Answer (score 1):

Here is another shot in the dark. You really need to be careful when naming columns and objects. Using reserved words is a bad habit and makes queries a lot more difficult than they need to be. Also when you are concatenating string values like this the result will be NULL if ANY of the columns are NULL.

```
select [status] = case when result = 'Passed' then 'corrected' end
    , [address] + ' ' + city + ' ' + [state] + ' ' + zip as occupancy
    , name 
from Occupancies OCC 
where result = 'Passed'
```

Comment: Glad you got it....but what is the solution? You posted the same comment on more than one response.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN result = 'Passed' then 'corrected' end as Status, 
       address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + zip as occupancy, 
       name 
FROM Occupancies
```